# using role instead of keys to get signed url in s3 but nothing returned and no errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, pre-signed-url

I tried if I use access key, it works fine but I am trying to get ride of access key and using role instead, but once I get ride of access key.  what I get in return is `www.aws.amazon.com`

```
    const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    const params = {Bucket: config.bucket, Expires: config.time, Key};
    const url = s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
    console.log('The URL is', url);
```

I even made sure my role is set right by going into my ec2 and run the cli command `aws s3 presign s3://bucket/path/file` which works fine I get the signed url in return though so this means my role is correct isn't it?

Thanks in advance for any advice / help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `getSignedUrl()` synchronously when using IAM roles.

> Note: You must ensure that you have static or previously resolved credentials if you call this method synchronously (with no callback), otherwise it may not properly sign the request. If you cannot guarantee this (you are using an asynchronous credential provider, i.e., EC2 IAM roles), you should always call this method with an asynchronous callback.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

```js
s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params, function (err, url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks thanks, so I have to use a callback and also realized I must use `promise` too else I can't get the returned url properly

Comment: i wasted couple hours on this.. AWS sdk should have thrown an error instead of silently failing and returning a placeholder :(

Comment: There is also a promise function `getSignedUrlPromise`. Anyway thank you sir Michael, this helped me a lot!

Comment: Hey, I used this function but still get placeholder
var params = {Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key', Expires: 60};
var promise = s3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', params);
promise.then(function(url) {
  console.log('The URL is', url);
}, function(err) { ... });